# Exclude oci specific sdk from helidon mp

Tags: oracle-cloud-infrastructure, helidon

We have a mp project and would like to know if there is a way to exclude all the dependencies added by helidon with respect to oci sdk,

Helidon 3.2.0 includes oci sdk by default, We dont need it, We would like add our own versions of sdk.

Comment: Which OCI SDK? Why would Helidon pack something related to OCI unless you specifically added a dependency tru some helidon provider bundles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Helidon won’t add OCI SDK dependencies unless you are using a Helidon feature that integrates with the OCI SDK. But Helidon does manage the version of the OCI SDK (via maven's `dependencyManagement`). There are a couple ways to override the version of the OCI SDK managed by Helidon. The simplest is to declare the following property in your application's pom.xml to override what Helidon specifies in its `dependencyManagement`:

```
<properties>
    <version.lib.oci>3.8.0</version.lib.oci>
</properties>
```

For more info see [Overriding-Helidon-Third-Party-Dependencies](https://github.com/helidon-io/helidon/wiki/Overriding-Helidon-Third-Party-Dependencies)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, This works, However may I please know the second way